# Linear stability analysis of the nonlinear Schrödinger's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stability-theory

I have the following equation -

$u_z = \frac{i}{2}u_{tt} + i|u|^2u$

where the subscripts denote partial derivatives with respect to the corresponding variable. I will be doing the stability analysis numerically, so for me, $u$ is a vector.

This equation has a solution $u(z,t) = sech(t)exp(iz/2)$.

My task is to determine the stability of the system for this solution.

I started by linearizing the equation as follows -

As $u$ is complex, let $u = v + iw$

Then - $$
\partial_{z}\left[\begin{array}{l}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]=\frac{-\beta}{2} J \partial_{t}^{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]+\gamma\left(v^{2}+w^{2}\right) J\left[\begin{array}{l}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $\mathrm{J}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right] .$

Therefore -

$$
\partial_{z}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v+\varepsilon \Delta v \\
w+\varepsilon \Delta w
\end{array}\right]=\frac{-\beta}{2} J \partial_{t}^{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v+\varepsilon \Delta v \\
w+\varepsilon \Delta w
\end{array}\right]+\gamma\left((v+\varepsilon \Delta v)^{2}+(w+\varepsilon \Delta w)^{2}\right) J\left[\begin{array}{c}
v+\varepsilon \Delta v \\
w+\varepsilon \Delta w
\end{array}\right]
$$
Keeping terms with $\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)$ and simplifying,
$$
\partial_{z}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v+\varepsilon \Delta v \\
w+\varepsilon \Delta w
\end{array}\right]=\partial_{z}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]+\varepsilon\left(\frac{-\beta}{2} J \partial_{t}^{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right]+\gamma\left(v^{2}+w^{2}\right) J\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right]+2 \gamma(w \Delta v+w \Delta w) \mathrm{J}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]\right)
$$

Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_{z}\left[\begin{array}{l}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right] &=\lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\left[\begin{array}{c}
v+\varepsilon \Delta v \\
w+\varepsilon \Delta w
\end{array}\right]-\partial_{z}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]}{\varepsilon} \\
&=\frac{-\beta}{2} J \partial_{t}^{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right]+\gamma\left(v^{2}+w^{2}\right) J\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right]+2 \gamma \mathrm{J}\left[\begin{array}{c}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
v & w
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right] .
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, the linearized equation is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right]=\mathscr{L}_{S M F}(v, w)\left[\begin{array}{c}
\Delta v \\
\Delta w
\end{array}\right]
$$

where

\begin{aligned}
&\mathscr{L}_{SMF}(v, w)=\mathrm{L}+\mathrm{M}_{1}(v, w)+\mathrm{M}_{2}(v, w) \\
&\mathrm{L}=-\frac{\beta}{2}J \partial_{t}^{2} \\
&\mathrm{M}_{1}(v, w)=\gamma\left(v^{2}+w^{2}\right) \mathrm{J} \\
&\mathrm{M}_{2}(v, w)=2 \gamma \mathrm{J}\left[\begin{array}{l}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
v & w
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}

And now I am stuck here. I have never dealt with PDEs before and I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using $z$ to represent time and $t$ to represent space (which would be somewhat odd)? And usually at this point, because your equation is linear, you would substitute in a solution ansatz for $v, w$ of the form $e^{i k t + \omega z}$ and determine some information about $k$ and $\omega$. Just so you know, a good book for this kind of stuff is J. D. Murray 'Mathematical Biology'.

Comment: In fiber optics, the NLS equation takes this form, but definitely not the first time I have been asked this. I'll take a look at the book. Thanks